# Less.js: if @color = value do something

Tags: css, less

Lets asume that i have a variable:

```
@title: blue;
```

And i need to know if there is anyway with the *iscolor* function to do something if the value is blue.
For example, if @title = blue import a @mixin to a class called "mytitle"
Im not really understanding the iscolor function and behavior
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, what you are trying to do is extremely simple:

```
@title: blue;

.mytitle when (@title = blue){
  /*Do stuff here*/
}
```

If `@title`'s value is equal to `blue`, add styles to `.mytitle`

Answer (score 1):

[iscolor](http://lesscss.org/functions/#type-functions-iscolor) is not appropriate here - it simply evaluates a string and tells you if the string is a valid color string. So trying something like `iscolor(@title)` will return `true` regardless of the color (as long as `@title` contains a valid color string).

**Update**: I think you're looking for the [Mixin Guard](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature) feature:

```
.mixin (@a) when (lightness(@a) >= 50%) {
  background-color: black;
}
.mixin (@a) when (lightness(@a) < 50%) {
  background-color: white;
}
.mixin (@a) {
  color: @a;
}
```

Comment: so, is there anyway to do something if the color is "blue" or not?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the `& when (@title = blue)` syntax, demonstrated in the [CSS Guards section of the documentation](http://lesscss.org/features/#css-guards-feature), to wrap your imports.

Comment: yes! its the `& when (@title = blue)` function what i needed!, you where right, the iscolor function was not what i needed